# Алгоритм слипания пузырей

Tags: c#, c++, алгоритм

Встретил на днях в игре механику соединяющихся пузырей. [Вот пример.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j6aNk7hAe24&feature=youtu.be)

Хотелось бы узнать как устроен алгоритм слипания похожих пузырьков, образование пузырьков, построение в подобие слипшихся окружностей, хотя бы примерно и почитать о похожих алгоритмах поподробнее, которые не привязаны жестко к квадратной сетке. Желательно примеры статей алгоритмов под c# или с++

Comment: Выглядит как реклама игры...

Comment: Для начала смотрите в сторону [диаграммы Вороного](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%92%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE)

Comment: @Monomax Увы нашел только данный пример, хотя пытался найти похожие алгоритмы в интернете, но так и не нашел. Поэтому прислал только этот пример, если найдете еще один пример похожих алгоритмов буду благодарен.

Comment: тогда, разъясните словами, какой алгоритм хотите получить? вам нужно отрисовать форму, определить границы, проверить наложения, что вы хотите получить, из вашего вопроса не совсем ясно, по сути, пока вопрос выглядит так: Вот видео, мне нужен алгоритм!

Comment: @Monomax Мне нужен алгоритм позволяющий создавать такие же формы(пузырьков) для генерации текстур, чтобы можно было получить такие же формы, где по отдельности пузырьки круглые, а вместе слипаются друг к другу. Диаграммы Вороного как сказали выше, вполне отвечают на мой вопрос, о структуре таких пузыриков

Comment: ну тогда, отредактируйте вопрос, что-бы всем было понятно.

Comment: Нашел статью рассказывающую о том как сделать данный эффект и где алгоритм пузыриков может встречаться в жизни [ https://habr.com/ru/post/309252/ ] ( статья ) Вот интерактивный пример пузырьков [ http://alexbeutel.com/webgl/voronoi.html ] П.С. радиус уменьшить до 100 и будут появляться круги